# Store a big array in mySQL

Tags: mysql, arrays, store

what is the best way to store a big array into a mySQL DB?

**First solution**

```
INSERT INTO `friendList` ( `userId` , `friendId` , `friendName` ) VALUES 
    ( '1', '3242343', 'bernd' ), 
    ( '1', '3242342', 'jusu' );
```

or with foreach

**second solution**

```
foreach (xxxx) {
     mysql_query("insert xxxx");
}
```

The first solution is better (cleaner and not so burdensome for the server, right?), but how do a create this insert command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest would be to use the multiple insert syntax (as you've described), but that's not what I would recommend to most people unless performance is truly vital. You also need to take care not to exceed the maximum query size (which can change between servers).

However, you could do this with prepared statements (PDO example) and still get reasonable performance:

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
));

$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `friendList` ( `userId` , `friendId` , `friendName` ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');

foreach ($data as $row) {
    $stmt->execute(array($row['id'], $row['friendid'], $row['friendname']));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store all data in a csv file or a text file and use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/load-data.html)

```
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE 'file_name.txt'
[REPLACE | IGNORE]
INTO TABLE tbl_name
[FIELDS
    [TERMINATED BY '\t']
    [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY '']
    [ESCAPED BY '\\' ]
]
[LINES 
    [STARTING BY '']    
    [TERMINATED BY '\n']
]
[IGNORE number LINES]
[(col_name,...)]
```

Comment: Is a text file really a good idea? If so, than i would prefere to store a json string. BTW: the maximum entries of my array are 4000.

Comment: The query doesn't work with json files.
Write in a file is faster than write in a db, so, to write 4000 lines in file is fast enough.

Comment: Nice! I haven't seen this used before. I know this is an old thread but out of curiosity, if you are going to write the data to a file wouldn't it be easier to just write a PHP file containing the values assigned to variables and just include it when needed?